# Problem with special characters while using LaTeX and the TeXMAKER

Tags: characters

When I type

> déterminer la bonne réponse

I get:

> d~A©terminer la bonne r~A©ponse

Comment: You seem to have an older tex system.  Try \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}.

Comment: Or remove an existing wrong inputenc call